# jquery slider not showing sliders after moved and beginning value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, uislider

I am trying to get a time slider to work in my mvc4 app.  The slider window will appear when clicking in the field but the sliders stay at the starting point.  If I click along the slider the value in the textbox changes but the slider handle never moves from the start.  I am using this [add-on](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).  I can't figure out why the handles will not move when I change the value or reflect the starting value.

I have my Time Editor Template as follows:

```
@model Nullable<TimeSpan>

@{
    TimeSpan? ts = null;
    if (Model != null)
    {
        ts = (System.TimeSpan)Model;

    }


    @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:hh\\:mm}", ts), new { @class = "timefield", type = "time"  })
}
```

Then I am including this javascript file.

```
$(function () {
    $(".timefield").timepicker();
});
```

My page includes the following Javascript:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/DatePickerReady.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/TimePickerReady.js"></script>


<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

The HTML generated by the editor template on the page is as follows:

```
<input name="ArrivalSceneTime" class="timefield hasDatepicker" id="ArrivalSceneTime" type="time" value="15:30"/>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works perfectly for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* css for timepicker */
        .ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }
        .ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
        .ui-timepicker-div dl dt { float: left; clear:left; padding: 0 0 0 5px; }
        .ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 45%; }
        .ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
        .ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        .ui-timepicker-rtl{ direction: rtl; }
        .ui-timepicker-rtl dl { text-align: right; padding: 0 5px 0 0; }
        .ui-timepicker-rtl dl dt{ float: right; clear: right; }
        .ui-timepicker-rtl dl dd { margin: 0 45% 10px 10px; }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#test").timepicker();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input id="test" name="test" type="text" value="15:30" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, why did you make it `type=time`? It works fine as a text and does not add the extra arrows that are unnecessary with this add-on.

If you need 12 hour intervals with AM and PM, you can change it to this:

```
$("#test").timepicker({
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt"
});
```

Comment: How did you know to add the smoothness css?  That is what was missing.  I don't see anything about adding it on the page.  After including that it works.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think that was the problem. I just always throw in the smoothness CSS theme when I deal with JQuery UI, so it isn't plain. It was more out of habit.